# How can I use the same Fluter app with multiple Firebase projects for SHA-256 fingerprints?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a flutter app and I'm using flutterfire configure (alternating between projects) to set up the connection to the project.  I have a production and test project, but `gradlew signingReport` produces SHA fingerprints that cannot be used twice.  I need the fingerprint to test the GoogleSignIn.

> One or more of your Android apps have a SHA-1 fingerprint and package
> name combination that's already in use

How do I create a separate fingerprint for the test project?